# Should I use "bindpopup" or "iframe" leaflet

Tags: iframe, mobile, popup, leaflet

I would like to make a user interface inside a leaflet popup (large amont of datas from mysql, buttons, little tchat system.etc..)

Should I bind all this html code + datas with the leaflet "bindpopup" function or should I better include another webpage into the popup with iframe ? or other idea ?

How does leaflet will display a very large popup on a mobile device?

Comment: The idea is to display a list of places on a map, and get all there info when opening the popup. But the user will have some fields he can modify, some advanced function like downloading a file generated from displayed datas etc...

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you really want to do, you'd better bind all the content to a pop-up.

Why? Because using an iframe implies [restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts#Cross-domain_iframes) if the frame is loaded from cross-domain. Also, iframe and main page do not share any CSS styles or even JavaScript objects, they both have their own "scopes" of execution.

So you'll have to "double" load css/js files for examples (even if browsers are smart, I mean you'll have to handle two or more html files), and perhaps you codes like `var L = window.top.L` from your `iframe`.

If you have a really nasty DOM as pop-up content, what you could do it to create a template in an .html file, then load it through ajax and append it to your pop-up content. For example :

```
<div class="popup-container">
    <div class="inner">
        <input type="text">
        ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Like this, this will create a logic separation between your map, and the content of your pop-up.